# What is the usual way to check if internet connection exists and if SMTP mail is sent?

Tags: vb.net

I'm sending emails through VB.NET like in showed code:

```
    Dim retval As Integer
    Dim attachment As System.Net.Mail.Attachment = Nothing
    If fileName <> "" Then
        attachment = New System.Net.Mail.Attachment(fileName)
    End If

    Dim client As New SmtpClient()
    With client
        .EnableSsl = True
        .Host = smtpServerAddress
        .Port = 587
        .DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
        .UseDefaultCredentials = False
        .Credentials = New NetworkCredential(FromEmailId, password)
        AddHandler .SendCompleted, AddressOf SendCompletedCallback
    End With

    Dim mail = New MailMessage(FromEmailId, toEmailId)
    With mail
        .Priority = MailPriority.High
        .Subject = subject
        .SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
        .IsBodyHtml = False
        If fileName <> "" Then
            .Attachments.Add(attachment)
        End If
        .Body = msgBody
        .BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
    End With

    Try
        client.SendAsync(mail, "")
        retval = 1
    Catch ex As Exception
        retval = 0
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try

    Return retval
```

This work's well.
Problem is only that my Try/Catch block dont react as expected if I'm not connected to internet. The only way I can know that mail didn't go out is that I don't receive message from callback what can take a long time. Also, I get returned 1 from function like email is sended properly.

Which is usual way to check if internet connection exists and if mail is start to be sended?

Comment: That's because it's **Async**.  The exception didn't happen yet.

Comment: I uses Async because then mail is sended from background otherwise my GUI will be blocked during sending. Am I right? Maybe I can use sinchronous sending from my own thread? Would this help?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch all exception thrown from SmtpClient you could send mail synchronously. If you prefer asynchronous way, use [SendMailAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193922.aspx) which returns Task instance on which you can call ContinueWith to set error handler:

```
client.SendMailAsync(mail).ContinueWith(t=>HandleError(t.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted)
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not much experienced in VB.NET so I don't know to apply your suggestion tip. Please if you can give me a bit wider example for catching what happen diring mail sending.